# Why did Falcon 9 boosters numbers skip B1027? What happened with it?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, booster

Looking at the [list of Falcon 9 launches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Falcon_9_and_Falcon_Heavy_launches) I noticed the booster numbers jump from B1026 to B1028. Anyone know what happened to B1027? Was it scrapped during manufacturing for some reason?

Comment: According to [r/spacex's wiki](https://www.reddit.com/r/spacex/wiki/cores#wiki_.288.29_inactive_cores), it was a Falcon Heavy core test article. I don't see the core number in the Facebook posts they link, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1027 was a Falcon Heavy structural test article that spent some time in the structural stand at McGregor before disappearing. It had no engines or fueling quick disconnects, so it couldn't have done propellant loading tests. After showing up in the stand, it disappeared.